# Why init is used in the add_action function as first argument (Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress

```
add_action('init', 'perfect_quotes_init');
```

I search on the google and wordpress.org but not got the right answer. So need an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init is the hook for the WordPress' initialization I mean it runs after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent. In the function, init is the event when the function (2nd argument) will be invoked.

```
add_action('init', 'perfect_quotes_init');
```

Above line tells the wordpress to invoke the function perfect_quotes_init when WordPress is ready, initialization (Boot up of WordPress) has done.